# Paypal merchant paying facilitator

Tags: php, paypal

I have set up a sandbox test case whereby I allow merchants to link and grant express checkout permission to my facilitator account, coupled with a second page where end users can purchase items from the merchants accounts. The problem I am having is that on completion of an express checkout, the facilitator is receiving all the money instead of the merchant. The merchant receives the credit card payment but immediately pays the facilitator the full amount.

Using this guide: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

I have then created an express checkout on behalf of the merchant account.

Auth details:

```
'mode' => 'sandbox',
'acct1.UserName' => 'dev-facilitator...',
'acct1.Password' => 'dev-facilitator_pw...',
'acct1.Signature' => 'dev-facilitator...',
'acct1.AppId' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
'acct1.accessToken' => $merchant_token,
'acct1.tokenSecret' => $merchant_secret
```

My code looks very similar to the example, with the assumption that the *PaymentDetailsType* passed through to *DoExpressCheckoutPayment* is that same as received from *GetExpressCheckoutDetails*

Everything appears to be working correctly except that when the users completes the payment the merchants paypal ends up looking like:

```
Purchase From, dev-facilitator, Completed, Details, -$250 NZD
Transfer From, Credit Card    , Completed, Details, $250 NZD
```

With the final result being:

```
Dev-facilitator balance: $250 NZD
Dev-merchant balance:    $0 NZD
```

I'm not sure where in the express checkout setup I should be specifying the kind of invoice the merchant should file against the facilitator in relation to the express checkout.

I can provide further code snippets if required.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the core of my problem is the fact that accessToken and tokenSecret are ignored if acct1.Subject is not also supplied (The email associated with the accessToken).

The second thing that caused confusion is that I was not paying attention to what account my buyer action was being performed against... Logging into my merchant account changed the cookies that I was using in the other tab for doing the express checkout. Thus the merchant account ended up being the buyer, and the facilitator the merchant... The *Purchase From*, *Transfer From*, was just the way credit card transactions are shown: IE first the credit card gets converted into paypal money and then that is used in the paypal purchase transaction.

Thus,

```
'mode' => 'sandbox',
'acct1.UserName' => 'dev-facilitator...',
'acct1.Password' => 'dev-facilitator_pw...',
'acct1.Signature' => 'dev-facilitator...',
'acct1.AppId' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
'acct1.Subject' => $merchant_email,
'acct1.accessToken' => $merchant_token,
'acct1.tokenSecret' => $merchant_secret
```

Is what I should have supplied.